# Correlation between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Similar questions have been asked, but I've not seen a lucid answer.  Forgive me for asking again.   I have two dataframes, and I simply want the correlation of the first data frame with each column in the second.   Here is code which does exactly what I want:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame( {'Y':np.random.randn(10) } )
df2=pd.DataFrame( {'X1':np.random.randn(10), 'X2':np.random.randn(10) ,'X3':np.random.randn(10) } )
for col in df2:
   print df1['Y'].corr(df2[col])
```

but it doesn't seem like I should be looping through the dataframe.  I was hoping that something as simple as

```
df1.corr(df2)
```

ought to get the job done.  Is there a clear way to perform this function without looping?

Comment: Not much wrong with that you could also do `df2.apply(df1['Y'].corr)` but this is looping over each col anyway

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`corrwith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html):

```
>>> df2.corrwith(df1.Y)
X1    0.051002
X2   -0.339775
X3    0.076935
dtype: float64
```