# python correlation test between single columns in two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I have two DF with a structure like that:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 6), columns=['T', 'U', 'V', 'X','Y','Z'])
```

I would like to test the correlation ('pearson') between every single column of DF1 with every single column of DF2. Then combine all the results into one correlation matrix.

A similar question has been asked in the past but my DF1 has several columns:

[Correlation between two dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157528/correlation-between-two-dataframes)

Any help on how to do this will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute it directly:

```
# center and standardize
df1vals = (df1.values - df1.values.mean(axis=0)) / df1.values.std(axis=0)
df2vals = (df2.values - df2.values.mean(axis=0)) / df2.values.std(axis=0)

# compute correlation
pearsons = df1vals.T.dot(df2vals) / len(df1)
```

This has shape `(len(df1), len(df2))`

If you really need to use `corrwith`, then:

```
pd.concat([
    df1.corrwith(df2[c]) for c in df2
], axis=1, keys=df2.columns)
```

Comment: Thank you. Since the number of rows is the same in both DF wouldn't be easier to use `corrwith()`? I was thinking `df2.corrwith(df1.A)`, `df2.corrwith(df1.B)` for every column in DF1 but then I don't know how to concatenate them